# ruby on rails - Use method as query column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I what to use a method as a query column on rails.

My model looks like this:

```
class CourseDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course, touch: true

  validates :date,  presence: true
  validates :start,  presence: true
  validates :end,  presence: true

  def start_datetime
    DateTime.new(date.year, date.month, date.day, start.hour, start.min, start.sec, start.zone)
  end

end
```

And what I want to do is something like this:

```
CourseDate.where("start_datetime > ?", Time.now)
```

This query is returning: `column "start_datetime" does not exist`

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What is the type of `start` column ?

Comment: The date column is of type Date and the start and end columns are of type Time

Comment: Can you change the format in the DB? What DB are you using?

Comment: I'm using postgres but I'm not getting your point. I want to use a method in my query, not a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports `date + time` ([doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)), so you could write the query like this :

```
CourseDate.where('"date" + "start" > ?', Time.now)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't query a ruby method as it doesn't exist in the database.

I would remove the date column and derive the date from the start column.

You could then query start `CourseDate.where("start > ?", Time.now)` knowing it contains the correct date as well as time.

```
class CourseDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course, touch: true

  validates :start,  presence: true
  validates :end,  presence: true
end
```

An alternative would be to add a datetime column called `start_datetime` and have a callback that sets its value using the logic you have in your method above `before_save`:

```
class CourseDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course, touch: true

  validates :date,  presence: true
  validates :start,  presence: true
  validates :end,  presence: true

  before_save :set_start_datetime

  private
  def set_start_datetime
    self.start_datetime = DateTime.new(
      date.year,
      date.month,
      date.day,
      start.hour,
      start.min,
      start.sec,
      start.zone
    )
  end
end
```

`CourseDate.where("start_datetime > ?", Time.now)` would now work.

Answer (score 0):

For the use case you mentioned, you are best off running `CourseDate.where start > NOW()`.  Note that this will use whatever time zone the database server is running in.

Comment: The problem is that start is of type Time and not DateTime